# Zend Framework with Handwritten Font

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am trying to use the [Amatic Font](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Amatic+SC) from Google in my PDF File but it gives me an Error like below. Could that be because the Font Type? I have tested with Open Sans and it is working.

> AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend_Pdf_Exception' with message 'Unable to read version 4 table' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/main/zend/library/Zend/Pdf/FileParser/Font/OpenType.php:555\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/main/zend/library/Zend/Pdf/FileParser/Font/OpenType.php(121):
>   Zend_Pdf_FileParser_Font_OpenType->_parseOs2Table()\n#1
>   /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/main/zend/library/Zend/Pdf/FileParser/Font/OpenType/TrueType.php(83):
>   Zend_Pdf_FileParser_Font_OpenType->parse()\n#2
>   /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/main/zend/library/Zend/Pdf/Font.php(701):
>   Zend_Pdf_FileParser_Font_OpenType_TrueType->parse()\n#3
>   /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/main/zend/library/Zend/Pdf/Font.php(615):
>   Zend_Pdf_Font::_extractTrueTypeFont(Object(Zend_Pdf_FileParserDataSource_File),
>   0)\n#4 /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/main/zend/invoice.php(27):
>   Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath('/var/www/vhosts...')\n#5 {main}\n\nNext
>   exception 'Zend_Pdf_Exception' wi...\n'

I am using this Script for my tests https://github.com/phpmasterdotcom/GeneratingInvoicesWithZendPdf/blob/master/public/invoice.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's happening is this: The Zend Framework code in OpenType.php explicitly checks the OS/2 table version of the font. Is it higher than 3, an exception is thrown. Your font has an OS/2 table version of 4 (which is the fifth version, there are at least 6 versions as far as I know).

Unfortunately, recent versions of the ZendPdf module (like [here on GitHub](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendPdf/blob/97279c6e470efd10e3d52875019de1926ccce3e8/library/ZendPdf/BinaryParser/Font/OpenType/AbstractOpenType.php)) still don't seem to support version 4 or higher. So apart from looking for another pdf generator - that does support version 4 - I fear there's no clean solution.

You could try editing the framework code, but of course that's a bit shady. As an alternative, apparently it should be able to change that version and regenerate the font. See [this post on the Tex forum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196014/error-after-installing-font-using-otftotfm-unknown-version-of-os-2-table-000) (the post AFTER the accepted answer). If you choose that path, probably you'll find better guidance on that forum.

Sorry I can't offer a better solution, but maybe it helps you understanding what's going on.